# How to use "HEVC with Alpha channel" videos in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

[At WWDC 2019, Apple announced that it was now handling HEVC with Alpha in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/506/), and state that it could be used in SceneKit.

I've been trying for hours to make that happen, without any luck.

My goal is to use a video as a texture on a SCNNode plane, and to make this plane transparent where the video is transparent.

I use the HEVC with Alpha video provided by Apple in [this xcode project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_hevc_video_with_alpha) (the video with 2 puppets).

I am developing with XCode 11.2 on a real device with iOS 13.2.

I tried different approaches.

### Approach 1. Using a AVPlayer as diffuse + transparent contents of my SCNNode material

```
let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: “puppets_with_alpha_hevc“, withExtension: "mov", subdirectory: "Assets.scnassets");
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = player
material.transparent.contents = player
plane?.geometry?.materials = [material];
player.play();
```

**Result :** the video is rendered with black pixels instead of transparent ones.

### Approach 2. Embed the AVPlayer in a SKVideoNode, then embed the SKVideoNode in a SKScene, and use the SKScene as a diffuse + material contents for the material of my SCNNode

This seems to be a common way to display video as material in SceneKit. Also, in [the example provided by apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_hevc_video_with_alpha) on how to render a “HEVC Video with alpha”, they use a SKVideoNode (but not in a SceneKit context).

```
let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
let spritescene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 360, height: 480))
let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 360.0 / 2.0, height: 480.0 / 2.0))
spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)
videoNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
spriteKitScene.addChild(videoNode)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
material.transparent.contents = spriteKitScene
plane?.geometry?.materials = [material];
```

**Result :** get this crash:

> validateFunctionArguments:3577: failed assertion `Fragment
>   Function(FastSingle_FragFunc): missing sampler binding at index 0 for
>   u_texture_sampler[0].'

**Note :** I don’t get this error when I use a regular HEVC video without an alpha channel.

### Approach 3. Use a material shader to copy alpha values from the video to the transparent map of the material.

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = player
material.shaderModifiers = [
    SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.surface :  "_surface.transparent.a = _surface.diffuse.a;"
];
plane?.geometry?.materials = [material];
```

**Result :** the video is rendered with black pixels instead of transparent ones. The alpha information does not seem to be in *_surface.diffuse.a*

### Approach 4. Using the shader with the the SKScene instead of the AVPlayer

**Result :** same error than with approach 2.

Does anyone have a clue about how to make this work ?

### Update : Tue, 07 Jan 2020

I tried my different approaches with iOS 13.3 and XCode 11.3.
=> Same results.

I just reported the bug to Apple, thanks for the link @mnuages.

### Update : Tue, 24 Mar 2020

The problem is fixed with the release of iOS 13.4.

HEVC Videos with transparency are taken into account straight away in SceneKit, without having to mess with the transparent content of the material, or with shaders.

Comment: Same issue with first snippet on iOS 13.2.3. Pixels are black instead of transparent. Same video (puppets) from wwdc sample code.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed in the iOS 13.4 beta

Comment: The `SKScene`/`SKVideoNode` crash appears to be when there is _only_ a video in the scene. I get this crash after simply removing the bridge background image from Apple's sample code.

Comment: ...adding a transparent sprite to the scene will fix it.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I have used approach2 with same code and same video in SceneKit , but getting same crash that you have mentioned. Tested in iOS 14.8.1 device.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet of code should work (without having to set the `transparent` material property). If you make the following change in the macOS SceneKit game template you get the correct result, however it doesn't work with the iOS SceneKit game template.

```swift
// retrieve the ship node
let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "puppets_with_alpha_hevc", withExtension: "mov", subdirectory: "art.scnassets");
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = player
player.play();
ship.enumerateHierarchy { (node, _) in
    if let geometry = node.geometry {
        geometry.materials = [material];
    }
}
```

This a case where one might want to [file a bug](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) for the iOS version to be fixed.

Comment: this seems to be fixed in the iOS 13.4 beta