# SceneKit support for HEVC with alpha channel

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to use HEVC video file with alpha channel in SceneKit. Used two different video files, one from apple([puppet video in asset in this apple demo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/using_hevc_video_with_alpha)) and from another resource([video 2](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbmpDVGxtSlVIbzl6YWpVQzRnc09JX1RqR2ZpUXxBQ3Jtc0trc3ZTbW9qM0tJY2JxNHFYTEF3VnVOaWNJdk5xQl9lQ3FoTTZOaWZTSXVYSHFNdFBMMXp0NTBDbjBqYTF5X3VDUEd4anljQVRjbXI5NDZUTDhSeVZKd3BkblNVYTdjOXZ2TDd6ZEYwNGFtZm5nZ2tKcw&q=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.ics.purdue.edu%2F%7Efwinkler%2Fdownload%2FAR_video_workshop.zip&v=4W5e6-TSpW0)).

Sample code:

```
  guard let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "puppets_with_alpha_hevc", withExtension: ".mov") else {
        print("Filed to load movie url")
        return
        
    }
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
    let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 360.0 / 2.0, height: 480.0 / 2.0))
    spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)
    videoNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
    spriteKitScene.addChild(videoNode)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
    material.transparent.contents = spriteKitScene
    guard let plane = container.childNode(withName: "video", recursively: true) else { return }
    plane.geometry?.materials = [material];
    plane.scale = SCNVector3(x: Float(referenceImage.physicalSize.width), y: Float(referenceImage.physicalSize.height), z: 1.0)
    videoNode.play()
```

Video is played against a reference image in AR.

Getting this exception when trying to play puppet video in SceneKit

> validateFunctionArguments:3838: failed assertion `Fragment Function(FastSingle_FragFunc): missing sampler binding at index 0 for u_texture_sampler[0].'

For the second video , app is not crashing but only black opaque background with audio is visible.

Using Xcode version: 14.2 and iOS version  : 14.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "HEVC with Alpha channel" videos in SceneKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720237/how-to-use-hevc-with-alpha-channel-videos-in-scenekit)

Comment: @mnuages I checked that question and added a comment there. As per that question, the issue is fixed in iOS 13.4, but I am still getting this issue in iOS 14.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### High Efficiency Video Coding with Alpha

##### SceneKit version

There's no need to use RGBA video with SpriteKit medium. You can use it directly with SceneKit.

(Tested on iOS 14.7 and iOS 17.0)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var player: AVPlayer? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.isPlaying = true
        
        // HEVC (H.265) with a premultiplied Alpha channel
        if let url =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "puppets", 
                                    withExtension: "mov") {
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            player?.play()
        }
        let model = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.3, height: 0.45))
        model.geometry?.materials[0].diffuse.contents = player
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(model)
    }
}
```

[image]

##### RealityKit version

The implementation of video material in RealityKit under visionOS looks similar. Also in visionOS, you can use [VideoPlayerComponent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/videoplayercomponent).

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var player: AVPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in               
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "puppets",
                                    withExtension: "mov")!

            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            var material = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: player!)
            
            let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 0.32,
                                                 height: 0.45)
            let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh,
                               materials: [material])
            content.add(model)
            player?.play()
            player?.volume = 0.2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to show transparent video over a reference image, your answer helped to rectify errors. Black opaque screen was shown when tried to play video in loop using AVPlayerLooper().